# Se em C# os "enum"s só aceitam tipos inteiros, por que aceitam um "char"?

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem, enums

Quando estamos aprendendo sobre `enum`s em C# é dito que eles só aceitam tipos numéricos inteiros. Portanto, logo pensamos em `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long` ou `ulong`. Porém o código abaixo também funciona, onde associamos elementos do `enum` a um tipo `char`. Por que isso acontece?

```
public enum PayCode {
    NotPaid = 'N',
    Paid = 'P'
}
```

Comment: Em c# o char é um inteiro de 16 bits (2 bytes), cada caractere é codificado num código numérico (procure por codificação UNICODE), portanto são tipos compatíveis para conversão. Existem inúmeras codificações, mas o padrão para strings em c# é UNICODE. Curiosidade: Emojis ocupam 2 caracteres (procure por surrogate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade o `enum` está usando o tipo `int` e eu posso provar:

```
using static System.Console;
 
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(PayCode.NotPaid.GetTypeCode());
        WriteLine((int)(PayCode.NotPaid));
        WriteLine((char)(PayCode.NotPaid));
        Teste('A');
        int x = 'B';
    }
    public static void Teste(int x) {}
}
 
public enum PayCode {
    NotPaid = 'N',
    Paid = 'P'
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/hBoMzN). E [no **repl.it**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7yJPPh). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enum/UnderlayingChar.cs).

Então o que aconteceu? Uma promoção do tipo `char` para um `int`. Todo `char` pode ser automaticamente considerado como um tipo numérico maior que ele, como o `int` se o local espera isso. Então, além de mostrar qual é o tipo interno do `enum`, usei mostrando em outros contextos onde espera um `int` que mandar um `char` é ok.

Essa regra foi definida pela linguagem. É correta? Em outras linguagens sempre foi fácil responder isso porque o tipo `char` realmente era só um número que por acaso podia ser interpretado como se fosse um caractere da tabela ASCII. Em C# poderia ser diferente já que ela tem melhores abstrações, e tem tipo que era numérico e não aceitaram converter automaticamente (`bool`), mas acharam que era melhor manter essa mesma semântica nesse caso.

E note que você pode mostrar o valor real da enumeração, se precisar mesmo fazer isso, dizendo como deseja mostrar e funciona tanto para inteiro como para caractere. Mas não se engane, na memória terá um inteiro guardado onde tiver um valor dessa enumeração, como mostra a primeira linha do código.

Comment: Eu vejo o tipo `char` como sendo apenas um número, no qual a implementação do `ToString` converte o mesmo para uma string contendo o caractere correspondente ao seu código. É errado pensar no tipo `char` dessa forma?

Comment: @user140828 não é errado, em todas linguagens [e visto isso de forma direta, embora essa ideia do `ToString()` não é bem assim, até é, isso está certo, mas você não precisa dele para ter um caractere, é só uma forma. Na verdade todos os tipos são só números que podem ser representados de alguma forma, computador não tem nada além de números (o que já é uma abstração). Pra mim só é esquisito pela inconsistência que eu falei. `bool` é só um número que tem dois valores que você interpreta como verdadeiro ou falso, mas é só o 0 ou 1, e a linguagem não deixa você fazer `int x = true`.

Comment: Só para complementar, pelo o que entendi, "por baixo dos panos" o Char é um tipo ushort, aceita exatamente o mesmo intervalo de valores (0-65.535).