# Quando usar byte, int, long, float, decimal quando usamos Enum?

Tags: c#, .net, desempenho, tipagem, enums

Já vi em vários projetos, com formas diferentes de lidar com *cast* de `enum`s, exemplo básico em .NET6:

```
using Teste;

int pessoaFisica = 1;
int pessoaJuridica = 2;

if((byte)TipoPessoaEnum.Fisica == pessoaFisica)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pessoa Física");
}
if ((long)TipoPessoaEnum.Juridica == pessoaJuridica)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pessoa Juridica");
}
if ((int)TipoPessoaEnum.Juridica == pessoaJuridica)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pessoa Juridica");
}
if ((float)TipoPessoaEnum.Juridica == pessoaJuridica)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pessoa Juridica");
}


namespace Teste{
    enum TipoPessoaEnum
    {
        Fisica = 1,
        Juridica = 2
    }
}
```

Veja que cada condição `if` lida de uma forma diferente, logo minha pergunta é, nesses cenários, qual é melhor usar? `byte`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `decimal`.

Qual desses é mais adequado usar?

Influencia no desempenho dependendo da forma que é usado?

Se tiver outras referências também, seja inglês ou português.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 1):

*Cast* de `enum` é amplamente utilizado, mas é muito comum não ser adequado. Um dos motivos para o `enum` existir é justamente não depender do seu valor.

Se ainda for usar, e o `enum` vai, garantidamente, até no máximo 255 tanto faz o que vai usar, se passar disso, `byte` não pode ser usado, e assim por diante. Mas precisa ter certeza que isso sempre será válido, *cast* não pode falhar.

Se vai comparar com um `int`, então faz sentido usar logo um `int` no *cast*, até porque o `enum` também provavelmente é um `int`, que é o tipo padrão se não for [especificado outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/457611/101). Assim evita promoções implícitas, que pode não ter custo, mas dificulta o entendimento, e pode eventualmente em alguma situação gerar um valor equivocado no futuro se mudar para algo um pouco mais complexo.

Se influenciar no desempenho será algo mínimo e por razões colaterais.

Dependendo do contexto pode ter até outra solução melhor, por exemplo [pegar a descrição do `enum`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82949/101).

`decimal` não pode ser usado.